# Retrieving last Login and Logout time in windows

Tags: windows, event-log

How do I get the last login and logout time of a Windows user using a VB script or command?

Tried using `C:\> net user username | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"` but it says username could not be found.

Comment: If it says `The user name could not be found.`, then you simply didn't provide the correct user name. The command in itself is fine.

Comment: Also do a "net user" and it will shows the actual username that you can do search for. Maybe you got mixed up between the username and display name.

Comment: You are substituting "username" with the actual username of the user you are checking on, aren't you?

Comment: If you log in to a domain, then you need to include the `/domain` option in the `net user` command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue could be due to the user you're requesting information on logging into a domain, rather than directly into the local PC.  This is often the case in the workplace (certainly where I work).

In these cases you can add the `/domain` option to the command, which will run the request on the domain controller of whatever the current domain is (such as the one you're logged in to):

```
C:\> net user <myusername> /domain | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"
Last logon                   9/5/2013 1:09 PM
```

This doesn't solve the logout time, but may help you to get halfway there.

Comment: Yes, I missed the domain name. Now it works fine but it gives me the Last Logon details for yesterday!!!

Comment: For those who want to get this information for their username: `net user %USERNAME% /domain | findstr /B /C:"Last logon"`